# UIAlertView reloads Views that were removed from their superView

Tags: ios, uialertview

I alloc and show an `UIAlertView` ( standard one button ). On

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{

    NSArray *a = [self.view subviews];

}
```

I get one element. The view that was in effect when I showed the Alert. On

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{

    NSArray *a = [self.view subviews];

}
```

I get 4 elements(??). UIAlertView somehow brings to life views that I previously have removed from their superview. Why??
Thanks, David

Comment: Are you using [self.viewToBeRemoved removeFromSuperview] to remove the views from the Superview?

Comment: Yes. I used removeFromSuperview and they were removed and appeared again with the Alert.

Answer (score 0):

Showing an alert is an activity related to UI and it's generally good practice to perform all the UI related tasks on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});
```

Inside the dispatch block, you should display your alert.

Hope this helps..

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I must confess I did not understand the answer. I don't know the call and I am trying to concentrate on Cocoa services and not go beyond that..

Comment: The 4 elements that you got in 
    **didPresentAlertView** must be the subviews of the UIAlertView. You can log the array of subviews in that method and check which subviews you got.

Comment: No. They are my removed classes. I verified it using  NSStringFromClass . I also am getting the views on the screen on the background of the alert.

Comment: I researched it further using the debugger and I was astonished to find that between the willPresentAlertView and the didPresentAlertView my code was resumed and ran as though the [alert show] was performed and clicked upon. One of the commands was to restore the removed views. I guess I am missing something. My code is basically [[alert alloc] initWithTitle] and then [alert show]. Should not my thread be freezed until the alert shows and the user clicks on the button ?